# Regular expressions for username and password

Tags: regex

Can you please help me with regular expressions. I need 2, one for username and one for password:

Username one:

1. Must be 8-15 characters and must start with a letter
2. May not contain special characters – only letters and numbers

Password one:

1. Must be 5-20 characters long
2. Must contain at least one lower-case letter (abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)
3. Must contain at least one number (0123456789)
4. Must not contain a colon (:); an ampersand (&); a period (.); a tilde (~); or a space.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Your fourth requirement is wrong.  Do not restrict password characters.  Do not restrict length, either.

Comment: Why do you want to put a maximum length on password? That's a really bad idea.

Comment: also: when asking regex questions, please also specify the language you're working in -- regex syntax differs between languages.

Comment: Length restirctions on user names are sensible, because user names must be stored in a database. Length restirctions on passwords are nonsense, because passwords are not stored in a database.

Comment: Voted down because this question seems like a "do it for me"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
username: /^[a-z][^\W_]{7,14}$/i

password: /^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=\D*\d)[^:&.~\s]{5,20}$/
```

explanation:

username:

```
 [a-z]    the first letter
 [^\W_]   equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9]
```

password:

```
(?=..)    is a lookahead that don't consume characters but only check
(?=[^a-z]*[a-z]) check if there is at least 1 lower case letter 
(?=\D*\d)   check if there is at least 1 digit
[^:&.~\s]  a character class that exclude all the characters you don't want
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Perl regex syntax.

For username:

```
/^[A-z][A-z0-9]{7,14}$/
```

For password, if you can split it into a few regular expressions, it is easier:

Check length and character set:

```
/^[^;&.~[:space:]]{5,20}$/
```

Check for at least one lowercase letter:

```
/[a-z]/
```

Check for at least one number:

```
/[0-9]/
```

Answer (score 0):

string length can't be checked using standard regexps, because it is out of the expressivness of standard regex. Though it may be added as an extension in some regex engines.

username:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

password:

```
[^: \&\.\~]*[a-z0-9]+[^:\&\.\~]+
```

you may use `{N,M}` instead of `+` to check for length as the other posts suggests, if that's supported by your regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

Username:

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{7,14}
```

Password:

```
[^:&\.~ ]{5,20} #checks wheter the length and the characters are right
```

You should check separately if there's at least one small case letter and at least one number, that's easy to do!

N.B.
Not sure what kind of regex are you using so I'm not sure how to match a whitespace (e.g. in **awk** you could use [[:space:]]).